# EF Core in .NET 6 console app won't update after SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, console-application, .net-6.0

I just tried to update about 900 items in SQL Server from a console app with `Foreach()`, but after everything is done, nothing is updated in SQL Server. I don't know why.

I start with debug and see everything work fine! API is ok, all vars are ok, even item.status that I want to get that string is OK! But after calling `SaveChanges()`, nothing happens to my database.

Here is my code:

```
Excel_DBContext context = new Excel_DBContext();
var excel = context.Sheets.Where(c => c.Status == null).ToList();
CallWebAPIAsync().Wait();

async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jamservice.pna.co.ir/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        Parameters countryList;
        string terminalId;
        string serial;
        HttpResponseMessage response;
     
        foreach (var item in excel)
        {
            terminalId = item.Terminal;
            serial = item.Serial;
            countryList = new Parameters() { TerminalID = terminalId, Serials = serial };

            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("services/api/RequestService/BindSerialToSwitch", countryList);

            var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var resultJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Excel>(resultString);

            Sheet findTerminal = context.Sheets.First(c => c.Terminal == terminalId);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                item.Status = resultJson.StatusTitle;
                context.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine("Record " + terminalId + " updated");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `DbSet`:

```
public partial class Sheet
{
    public string? Terminal { get; set; }
    public string? Serial { get; set; }
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
}
```

Class for API:

```
public class Excel
{
    public string? Terminal { get; set; }
    public string? Serial { get; set; }
    public string? StatusTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you said, EF6, but i see no sign of it. This is like - here is my code, why is this not working

Comment: It's Using EFCore for working with DB, you need my code for dbcontext?

Comment: we can't tell anything from the code you posted. If `savechanges` is not working than that is the code you need to post. Why do we need your webservice calls? We can't tell anything from that

Comment: all the code is there! nothing more!!! what do u need to see, just tell me and I put it there, it's just DBContext that I didn't posted. thats simple DBContext with just one table.

Comment: `var results = context.SaveChanges();` returns the number of rows affected.  See what that is.

Comment: result returns zero! I know that it doesn't affect rows, even 1! but I think I wrote my code right! why is there problem?

Comment: I don't see modification done to what you trying to save

Comment: I want to update the Status Column of the table! in there I put item.status and I checked that it gets full then Save happens but no saves actually.

Comment: @AliJebali, try to debug your app - see what `StatusTitle` field you http response has, and what value of your `context.Entry(item).State` is after setting new value before `context.SaveChanges()` call. Debugger is your best friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer and wanted to share it with you.
Because My TerminalId didn't have any duplicate I didn't put any primary key.
now I've tested that if I set TerminalId to primary Key in DB and set primary in DBContext and so on... everything works fine.
thank you for all your helps. special thanks to @Ryan because of that Code I get the Exception for primary key and without that, there was no exception.

Comment: **Database Principle #1** - ***EVERY*** (real) table should ***ALWAYS*** have a primary key - no exceptions